# Where is dockerfile located in default laravel sail project

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-sail

Building a laravel project using laravel sail documentation. As mentioned in the docker-compose.yml file it mentions *dockerfile: Dockerfile*. But it is not located in the root folder, so where is it?

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            **dockerfile: Dockerfile**
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's at the path of the `context`: `./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile`

See: https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile

Answer (score 9):

For customization of the Dockerfile in your app you can publish the vendor files in your applications directory with the following command:

```html
sail artisan sail:publish
```

More Info see: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#sail-customization